# Is there a way to wait for a workbook to open?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a program in VBA which opens a workbook from a server and gets information from some cells.
Because the location of the information will always be different I am using many parameters.

The program moves faster than it can open the second workbook and the variable for it doesn't contain anything or the right address, it may get the address of the current workbook.

I tried `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)`. It feels like the wait also stops from opening the second workbook because I get the out of range error and after it opens the second workbook.

While stepping through the program with F8 it works. I step until the new workbook opens and then run the next line where I set the address of the new workbook.
With local files no wait needed

When stepping through the code with F8, the workbook from the hyperlink opens in about 5-8 seconds but when I run it with F5 the
`wkb.FollowHyperlink` command returns an error in the next steps since the `wkb_activ = ActiveWorkbook` will be the same workbook as the one that I started the macro (the one that is supposed to receive information). Even though I put a wait time of over a minute the hyperlink will not open the workbook. When I close the error message, the files opens.

The code for the workbook opening. The variable col_index is a number and sheet_index is the variable for the sheet in the first workbook which gets the information.

```vb
For i = 2 To lastrow  

    If IsEmpty(sheet_index.Cells(i, col_index).Value) Then
        End
    Else
        wkb.FollowHyperlink Address:=sheet_index.Cells(i, col_index).Value, NewWindow:=True        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)
        Set wkb_activ = ActiveWorkbook
    End If
```

Comment: can you give an example of what `sheet_index.Cells(i, col_index)` is? local file, actual web address etc

Comment: It's a hyperlink to another workbook on the server.  That's where it should extract the information from.

Comment: If it's executing the line to follow a hyperlink, and it begins the wait immediately after, 15 seconds may be enough time for the site to load some aspect (and do that fun delay from Excel activating a browser), but may not always be the case.  Is there a check you can perform on the webpage?  That would be the better option than putting in a wait.

Comment: It is enough time but the my problem it's that it feels like Application.Wait also freezes the process of opening and loading the new worksheet. After the 15 second delay I get the "out of range error" since wkb_activ doesn't have the new address and right after it opens and loads properly the new worksheet.

Comment: Why not use `Set wkb_activ = Workbooks.Open(pathHere)` to open the file?

Comment: I tried setting the path, no luck, kept getting the error for not finding the file. I've tried different methods, with the same result. I managed with the help of a friend. He created a new Sub with a loop in which it does nothing until the timer is greater than the value we chose. Here is the code:  

`Sub time(total)
starting_time = Timer  
Do  
DoEvents 
Loop Until (Timer - starting_time) >= total  
End Sub`  
And in the main Sub:   

`wkb.FollowHyperlink Address:=sheet_index.Cells(i, col_index).Value NewWindow:=True
time (30)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. We created a new Sub with a loop in which it does nothing until the timer is greater than the value we chose. Here is the code:

```
Sub time(total) 
starting_time = Timer   
Do   
DoEvents  
Loop Until (Timer - starting_time) >= total   
End Sub
```

And in the main Sub we have added the time(30) for a 30 second timer.

```
wkb.FollowHyperlink Address:=sheet_index.Cells(i, col_index).Value NewWindow:=True 
time (30)
Set wkb_activ = ActiveWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built on Catalin's solution, this code will continue to check to see if a workbook has been opened until a timeout is reached

```
Public Function AwaitWorkbookOpenedByHyperlink(FilepathHyperlink As String, Optional TimeoutInSeconds As Integer = 5) As Workbook
    

    Dim StartingWbkCount As Integer, CurrentWbkCount As Integer
    StartingWbkCount = Workbooks.Count
    CurrentWbkCount = Workbooks.Count
    
    Dim StartTime As Long
    StartTime = Timer
    Dim ElapsedTime As Long
    ElapsedTime = 0
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=FilepathHyperlink
    
    Do
        Dim SplitTime As Long
        SplitTime = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until (Timer - SplitTime) >= 0.2
        
        CurrentWbkCount = Workbooks.Count
        If StartingWbkCount <> CurrentWbkCount Then
            Set AwaitWorkbookOpenedByHyperlink = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ElapsedTime = Timer - StartTime
        
    Loop Until ElapsedTime > TimeoutInSeconds
    
    Set AwaitWorkbookOpenedByHyperlink = Nothing
    
End Function
```